# CSV to map/card

Tags: windows, csv

I have a CSV file with 500 users in it, with adresses, age etc.
I would love to have some graphic on that, importing this csv file into some sort of 
map program, then display it.

I have found several online programs like cardtoDB or arcgis
the problem is just like google maps, these are online solutions.
I want to download the program and run it from my computer, as its important to me this csv file never actually gets uploaded.

I've tried doing it in microsoft mappoint. It imported the .csv file fine, the program was not very good for this purpose though, I had no control of the graphics, it was confusing and in big clusters of users it would just make a big circle.
Clearly mappoint is not meant to be used as a statistics program.

So I'm looking for alternatives: it's not an issue the program costs money, of course I would like it to have a demo or trial first so I can check it actually works with the csv file I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your description of your data, I think you'll need a GIS solution because of the need to geoverify addresses to a map.  Arcgis is a really good solution for that and there are local versions (Arcview being the cheapest) that you don't have to upload any data for full functionality.

If you have Lat/Long data for your points then you could use Accuglobe ([www.accuglobe.net](http://www.accuglobe.net)).  It is a free download, has pretty solid, basic GIS functionality and can import XY data and plot it.  I don't think they've ever added address georeferencing, but the current versions may have it as well.

Comment: alright thank you I will attempt to download Arcview and see where that takes me... then return here

Comment: okay so went through the extremely hard work of downloading a trial of arcview with is now refered to as arcsoft desktop version or something like that..  so after having to give them 500 lines of information about myself, through several activation steps ;) I was allowed to install download manager, but when I attempt to download the program it just says "cannot connect to server" I guess I have to try from a less 'safe' computer at home and not from work

Comment: Unfortunately that is part of dealing with ESRI-they are very tight with software protection.  The good news is that the product generally lives up to its expectations-I've never not been able to do what I've needed with their software.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Some options I've used:

- [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)
- [Excel](https://www.google.nl/search?q=%2b%22excel%20charts%22)
- [R](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHu5vgBZ1yQ) (quite a learning curve)